# Is it necessary to have a maxlength validation message on an input in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

Using the `maxlength` attribute on a form element not only wires up Angular's built-in validation, but it also prevents input beyond the specified length from being entered into the text box. Does that mean that showing an error message for breaking `maxlength` validation is pointless because the browser already enforces the limit? In my example below, it seems that the second error message never even appears.

```html
<input class="form-control" #fName="ngModel" required maxlength="25" />
<div class="form-error-wrapper" *ngIf="fName.invalid && (fName.dirty || fName.touched)">
  <div *ngIf="fName.hasError('required')" class="form-error">
    First name is required
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="fName.hasError('maxlength')" class="form-error">
    First name cannot be longer than 25 characters.
  </div>
</div>
```

What's the point of letting the user know they're breaking a rule if the browser doesn't let them break it in the first place?

Comment: Its all down to ux . personally i prefer to let the user break the rule and alert him (this way he knows whats happening) rather than wondering why he cant type more chars....but yeah no point having both...one nulls the other

Comment: From a usability point of view, I think you shouldn't ever use maxlength. It simply doesn't benefit anyone (the programmer has to validate it server anyway). A user that knows the length doesn't need it, and a user that doesn't  doesn't always know why his keyboard stopped working. Not to mention auto cropping while using copy/paste which is impossible to detect by the user since he is probably looking at the keyboard. The preferred way is displaying an error message explaining the problem, just like in this comment box :) This also applies to "number" type and any other blocking of input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. If you are going to have a max length validation, then you should not implement the html maxlength property. Otherwise, the user can never violate that rule and thus the error message will never show up. That error message would be used only in the case where you don't set the max length property. Either way is fine. It just depends on preference.